# Symfony 3. FOSUserBundle как изменить проверку хэша при авторизации

Tags: symfony2, symfony3, fosuserbundle

Для работы с юзерами подключил FOSUserBundle.
При создании юзера или проверке пароля бандл использует один из указанных алгоритмов:bcrypt, sha512 и т.д.
Как мне указать свой собственный алгоритм проверки хеша?
Таблица с юзерами приходит со стороннего проекта. Нужно сделать авторизацию по такому же логину и паролю как в таблице, но хеш пароля в этой таблице получен таким способом base64_encode(md5('пароль', true) и в начало хэша добавляется определенный набор симоволов.

Answer (score 2):

Сам и отвечу :)

Надо переопределить encodePassword

```
<?php
namespace UserBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\PasswordEncoderInterface;

class AmsPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoderInterface
{
   public function encodePassword($raw, $salt)
   {
       $hash = "{MD5}" . base64_encode(md5($raw, true));
       return $hash;
   }

   public function isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt)
   {
      // TODO: Implement isPasswordValid() method.
      return $encoded === $this->encodePassword($raw, $salt);
   }
```

}